# Detect changes to angular ui-grid's column visibility

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I would like to store which columns the user has shown/hidden so I can save the user's preferences.

How can I detect when a column's visibility has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey did you try using columnVisibilityChanged(scope, callBack) api?

Something like:

```
gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged( $scope, function (column) {
  // do something
} );
```

Refer http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have not tried that. I didn't know it was there, but it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!